How to configure AKS Monitoring cost presets with data collection rule associations using bicep?
I would like to configure AKS Monitor in Azure Kubernetes Service by setting the Cost Presets to Logs And Events using bicep.
I wrote the code below but it does not change the value of the cost preset. Data Collection Rules are correctly set but don't reflect in AKS Monitoring. Am I missing something here?
The following is created:

Data Collection Rules (MSCI-westeurope-abc-aks-we-dev). Properly reflects changed values (Cost Presets) when looking up in the Azure Portal, however it does not reflect in Azure Kubernetes Service.
Data Collection Rules Association, deployment seems OK but does not seem to link between Data Collection Rule and AKS Monitoring.

To simulate do the following in the Azure Portal:

Create a Resource Group named: aks-dev

Create an Azure Kubernetes Service called abc-aks-we-dev (within the aks-dev resource group)
In Azure DevOps:

Store the bicep code below in a repository called Deploy-Bicep

Add a new pipeline refering to azure-pipelines.yml


main.bicep
@description('Prefix')
param prefix string = 'abc'
@description('Environment')
param env string = 'dev'
@description('Location')
param loc string = resourceGroup().location

param skuName string = 'pergb2018'
param retentionInDays int = 30
param dailyQuotaGb int = 1

module logAnalytics 'loganalytics.bicep' = {
  name: 'log-analytics'
  params: {
    prefix: prefix
    env: env
    loc: loc
    retentionInDays: retentionInDays
    skuName: skuName
    dailyQuotaGb: dailyQuotaGb
  }
}

module appInsights 'appInsights.bicep' = {
  name: 'application-insights'
  params: {
    prefix: prefix
    env: env
    loc: loc
    retentionInDays: retentionInDays
    logAnalyticsId: logAnalytics.outputs.loganalyticsId
  }
}

loganalytics.bicep
@description('Prefix')
param prefix string = 'abc'
@description('Environment')
param env string = 'dev'
@description('Location')
param loc string = resourceGroup().location

param skuName string = 'pergb2018'
param retentionInDays int = 30
param dailyQuotaGb int = 2

var name = '${prefix}-log-we-${env}'

resource loganalytics 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-10-01' = {
  name: name
  location: loc
  properties: {
    sku: {
      name: skuName
    }
    workspaceCapping: {
      dailyQuotaGb: dailyQuotaGb
    }
    retentionInDays: retentionInDays
  }

}

output loganalyticsId string = loganalytics.id

appInsights.bicep
@description('Prefix')
param prefix string = 'abc'
@description('Environment')
param env string = 'dev'
@description('Location')
param loc string = resourceGroup().location
param retentionInDays int = 1
@description('LogAnalytics Id')
param logAnalyticsId string

resource appInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: '${prefix}-appi-we-${env}'
  kind: 'other'
  location: loc
  properties:{
    Application_Type:'other'
    RetentionInDays: retentionInDays
    IngestionMode: 'LogAnalytics'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsId
  }
}

resource appInsights_dataCollection 'Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules@2022-06-01' = {
  properties: {
    dataSources: {
      extensions: [
        {
          streams: [
            'Microsoft-ContainerLog'
            'Microsoft-ContainerLogV2'
            'Microsoft-KubeEvents'
            'Microsoft-KubePodInventory'
          ]
          extensionName: 'ContainerInsights'
          extensionSettings: {
            dataCollectionSettings: {
              interval: '5m'
              namespaceFilteringMode: 'Off'
              enableContainerLogV2: true
            }
          }
          name: 'ContainerInsightsExtension'
        }
      ]
    }
    destinations: {
      logAnalytics: [
        {
          workspaceResourceId: resourceId('Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces', '${prefix}-log-we-${env}')
          name: 'ciworkspace'
        }
      ]
    }
    dataFlows: [
      {
        streams: [
          'Microsoft-ContainerLog'
          'Microsoft-ContainerLogV2'
          'Microsoft-KubeEvents'
          'Microsoft-KubePodInventory'
        ]
        destinations: [
          'ciworkspace'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
  location: loc
  kind: 'Linux'
  name: 'MSCI-${loc}-abc-aks-we-${env}'
}

resource managedCluster 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2022-02-01' existing = {
  name: '${prefix}-aks-we-${env}'
}

resource appInsights_dataCollectionRuleAssociations 'Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRuleAssociations@2022-06-01' = {
  name: 'ContainerInsightsExtension'
  scope: managedCluster
  properties: {
    dataCollectionRuleId: appInsights_dataCollection.id
    description: 'Association of data collection rule. Deleting this association will break the data collection for this AKS Cluster.'
  }
}
``

azure-pipelines.yml
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Deploy
  jobs:
  - job: DeployInfrastructure
    steps:
    - checkout: self

    - task: AzureCLI@2
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: 'bicep-aks-test'
        scriptType: 'bash'
        scriptLocation: 'inlineScript'
        inlineScript: |
          az group create --name aks-dev --location westeurope

          az deployment group create \
            --resource-group aks-dev \
            --template-file main.bicep \

Monitor Settings cost presets are set to Standard


Please share screenshots to clarify "Properly reflects changed values (Cost Presets) when looking up in the Azure Portal" and "does not reflect in Azure Kubernetes Service". 2. "Data Collection Rules are correctly set but don't reflect in AKS Monitoring" Please share a screenshot to show how it looks like in AKS monitoring. 3. What's the result if you deploy on your local machine using the same bicep files?


Check whether this blog is helpful for you Configure AKS Monitoring: Cost Presets for Logs & Events using Bicep.

@ZiyangLiu-MSFT please see at the end of my start post a screenshot to: "Monitor Settings cost presets are set to Standard".

Testing the code shared by @Vinay B, it works fine. Have you tried it? He just deployed logAnalyticsWorkspace, aksCluster, dataCollectionRule and dcrAssociation.


Configure AKS Monitoring cost presets with data collection rule associations using bicep

I tried an updated configuration for the where it successfully establishes the connection between DCR and cluster by making few changes in the configuration.
Deployment:
param location string = 'eastus'
param clusterName string = 'vksbCluster'
param kubernetesVersion string = '1.30.3'
param logAnalyticsWorkspaceName string = 'mvksbWorkspace'
param dcrName string = 'vskbDCR'

var servicePrincipalClientId = 'xxxxxx-e29a-xxxx-xxxx-8016e579e93c'
var servicePrincipalClientSecret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

resource logAnalyticsWorkspace 'Microsoft.OperationalInsights/workspaces@2020-08-01' = {
  name: logAnalyticsWorkspaceName
  location: location
  properties: {
    retentionInDays: 30  
    workspaceCapping: {
      dailyQuotaGb: 5  
    }
  }
}

resource aksCluster 'Microsoft.ContainerService/managedClusters@2021-03-01' = {
  name: clusterName
  location: location
  properties: {
    kubernetesVersion: kubernetesVersion
    agentPoolProfiles: [
      {
        name: 'nodepool1'
        count: 3
        vmSize: 'Standard_DS2_v2'
        osType: 'Linux'
        type: 'VirtualMachineScaleSets'
        mode: 'System'
      }
    ]
    enableRBAC: true
    dnsPrefix: 'aks'
    addonProfiles: {
      omsagent: {
        enabled: true
        config: {
          logAnalyticsWorkspaceResourceID: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
        }
      }
    }
    servicePrincipalProfile: {
      clientId: servicePrincipalClientId
      secret: servicePrincipalClientSecret
    }
  }
}

resource dataCollectionRule 'Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules@2022-06-01' = {
  name: dcrName
  location: location
  properties: {
    dataSources: {
      extensions: [
        {
          streams: [
            'Microsoft-ContainerLog'
            'Microsoft-ContainerLogV2'
            'Microsoft-KubeEvents'
            'Microsoft-KubePodInventory'
          ]
          extensionName: 'ContainerInsights'
          extensionSettings: {
            dataCollectionSettings: {
              interval: '5m'
              namespaceFilteringMode: 'Off'
              enableContainerLogV2: true
            }
          }
          name: 'ContainerInsightsExtension'
        }
      ]
    }
    destinations: {
      logAnalytics: [
        {
          workspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
          name: 'ciworkspace'
        }
      ]
    }
    dataFlows: [
      {
        streams: [
          'Microsoft-ContainerLog'
          'Microsoft-ContainerLogV2'
          'Microsoft-KubeEvents'
          'Microsoft-KubePodInventory'
        ]
        destinations: [
          'ciworkspace'
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}

resource dcrAssociation 'Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRuleAssociations@2022-06-01' = {
  name: 'ContainerInsightsExtension'
  scope: aksCluster
  properties: {
    dataCollectionRuleId: dataCollectionRule.id
    description: 'Association of data collection rule with AKS.'
  }
}

Deployment:



Refer:
Configure AKS Monitoring Cost Presets with Bicep (trycatchdebug.net)
Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRuleAssociations 2022-06-01 - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn
Microsoft.Insights/dataCollectionRules 2022-06-01 - Bicep, ARM template & Terraform AzAPI reference | Microsoft Learn
